# Check two types in a parameter of the response

Tags: karate

i'm a little new in this framework. I was wondering if i can check two different types of parameter (#number, #string, etc...) in the same response parameter.

For example, in this JSON the parameter **surname** sometimes can be null and sometimes has content

```
{
   "name": "Eduard",
   "surname": "Rodriguez",
   "age": 30
}
```

Can i check if the same parameter in the response is #string and #null. Something like:

```
{
   "name": "#string",
   "surname": "#null,#string",
   "age": #number
}
```

I hope the question is clear.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the docs: https://github.com/intuit/karate#null-and-notpresent

```
* match response == { name: '#string', surname: '##string', age: '#number' }
```